# ros-electric : package => motion_planning_common

Tags: ros, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recently install ROS Electric (before I had Diamondback). But, with this new release, I can't find the package "motion_planning_common".

I use Ubuntu 11.04 and this package does not appear in the package manager (synaptic) but in the Diamondback version, it appears...

Do you know if this package is plan to be added ?
I need it for my robot and installing the Diamondback version does not seem to work.

Thanks,
Jo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11352/ros-electric-:-package-=%3E-motion_planning_common/) by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2011-09-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Packages from motion_planning_common that are still being maintained now live in [arm_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation).

Note also that many of the message packages that existed in motion_planning_common have been swallowed up by arm_navigation_msgs.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) on 2011-09-29**:
That's right, the messages I was looking for are now in the arm_navigation_msgs ! Thanks !